# How to call a new php page inside a plugin page?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a **custom plugin** that is accessible via WordPress sidebar, this is the option page of my plugin.

How do I called a new page inside my option plugin page?

```
<li><a href="<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/myPlugin/create.php">Create</a></li>
```

Apparently, this code above, will display `create.php` but I want this page to be displayed inside the WordPress wp-admin, with the sidebar and all..

Comment: Have you looked up [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) or [`add_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) in the Codex?

Comment: add_menu_page()  function will help you  to add the option